# Scraping silver price with php curl xpath

Tags: php, curl, xpath, scraper

```
    <?php
$curl = curl_init('https://silvergoldbull.com/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(!empty($curl)){ //if any html is actually returned

$pokemon_doc = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$pokemon_doc->loadHTML($page);
libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

$pokemon_xpath = new DOMXPath($pokemon_doc);

$silverprice = $pokemon_xpath->evaluate('string(/html/body/nav/div[3]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a/span/div/div/strong)'); //
echo $silverprice;
}
else {
    print "Not found";
}
?>
```

Trying to pull the price of silver but keep getting a blank page not sure if its cause it is a https or if i got the wrong xpath any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: See if you are getting the page loaded first. If not loaded your error is not with the Xpath but with Curl, Most of the time you need to turn off ssl varifier while using urls with SSL / HTTPS  add this to the curl options `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Comment: Page is still coming up blank :/

Comment: i used a differnt site for scraping the silver price it seemed to work :)